# Stack Overflow top bar not displaying for private developer story traditional view

Tags: bug, developer-story, top-bar

When a user set his/her developer story Visibility: Private, then viewing the story it throws the **Page Not Found**.

But for the **story view** error page it has the Stack Overflow header (top bar), but for the **traditional view** error page it lost the the header.

[**Story view:**](https://stackoverflow.com/story/arulkumar)

[image]

[**Traditional view:**](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/arulkumar)

[image]